# How to close pop up error message

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an application that when a user leaves a text field empty or does not make the two passwords match, an error alert will be presented.

Issue is when the information is correct and the two passwords match, the error alert is still being presented.

The code can be seen below:

```
//creating an action that will check when the sign up button is selected.

@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text;

    // if one of the fields is empty the user must repeat the password
    if ((userEmail?.isEmpty)! || (userPassword?.isEmpty)! || (userRepeatPassword != nil)) {

        //this is the alert pop up shown to the user.
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Error!!!!!!",
            message: "Something Went Wrong, Try Again",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
        )

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "Cancel",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive) { (action) in 

        }

        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in

        }

        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true){ () -> Void in
            return;
        }
    }

func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    //check if password and repeat password are the same
    if (userPassword != userRepeatPassword) {

        //display an alert message, user will not be able to continue // not too sure if this works
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Error!!!!!!",
            message: "Something Went Wrong Try Again",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
        )

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "Cancel",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive) { (action) in

        }

        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in

        }

        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true){ () -> Void in
            return;
        }
```

When the correct information has been entered the user should be able to see a confirmation stating the account has been created.

```
//display prompt message (confirmation)

//this will show a message to the user showing that the registration has been successful this is not working
func showAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You", message: "Registration Has Been Completed. Thank You", preferredStyle: .alert)      

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true){ () -> Void in
        return;
    }
}
```

This also does not show up.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please DO NOT SCREAM AT PEOPLE and read how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where is showAlert being called?

Comment: Downvoted for the shouting and begging.

Comment: I attempted to use alert.show() but was recieving loads of errors.

Comment: the caps lock was purely by accident and i do apolgise, just got an assignment due and i cannot seem to move past this error which is frustrating

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the whole thing on how you can go about this problem. You can reference it from here

```
@IBOutlet var userNameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var confirmPasswordField: UITextField!

@IBAction func registerButtonTapped() {

    if userNameField.text == "" && passwordfield.text == "" && confirmPasswordField.text == "" {
        alertController(title: "Error", message: "One or more fields are missing", cancelTitle: "Try again!")
    } else {

        if passwordfield.text != confirmPasswordField.text {
            alertController(title: "Error", message: "Your passwords do not match", cancelTitle: "Try again!")
        } else {
            //switch views, or do whatever you want when the user correctly enters in their information
        }
    }

}

func alertController(title: String, message: String, cancelTitle: String) {


    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: .cancel)

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi Cyril thank you for your comments, I have made all the suggestions you have stated and for some reason it is still showing the error message when all the fields and passwords have been entered correctly.

Comment: Hi also i have got an additional error saying Thread 1 Signal SIGABRIT

Comment: I should have read your question a little more carefully. I'll answer it one I get to a computer.

Comment: I made changes to my original answer.

Comment: Hi Cyril, I have tried to make those changes however those changes created multiple errors and would not compile.

Comment: @SimranKaur can you share a screenshot of your error

Comment: Hello now no errors are shown on the screen however now when the password is typed incorrectly it does not notify the user and when the field is left empty it also does not notify the user. however it is running fine but not doing that @CyrilIvarGarcia

Comment: @SimranKaur oksy, well that is weird. Idk if this will work but i made changes to my code. Instead of using the || statement i used an && statement